# ViewBinding with dynamically added content

Tags: java, kotlin, android-layout, inheritance, android-viewbinding

I have base activity implementing some features for every screen of my app. Every child activity then overrides method with its XML layout.

**BaseActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.base_screen);
    View mFormView = findViewById(R.id.pnContent);
    if (getContentAreaLayoutId() != 0) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View contentLayout = inflater.inflate(getContentAreaLayoutId(), (ViewGroup) mFormView, false);
        ((ViewGroup) mFormView).addView(contentLayout, 0);
    }
}
```

**ChildActivity**

```
override fun getContentAreaLayoutId(): Int = R.layout.standard_content_settings
```

Now I would like to use view binding in my child activities. I was thinking about something like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val binding = StandardContentSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}
```

But when I used binding (`binding.edURL.setText("test")`), view does not change and stays empty. I guess I'm using view binding wrong and have to inflate it with another way?

Comment: After inflating the binding, you can add `binding.root` to a ViewGroup from the superclass’s layout. But I think BaseActivities should be avoided. Composition over inheritance! You can do basically the same thing with a utility function and maybe `<include>` layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inflate the binding object in the `BaseActivity` and expose methods to child activities to get the binding object.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //base binding
    private BaseScreenBinding baseBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // always call base methods, your code didnt have those calls.

        baseBinding = BaseScreenBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(baseBinding.getRoot());

        //your existing code to inflate child content
        View mFormView = baseBinding.pnContent;
        if (getContentAreaLayoutId() != 0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View contentLayout = inflater.inflate(getContentAreaLayoutId(), (ViewGroup) mFormView, false);
            ((ViewGroup) mFormView).addView(contentLayout, 0);
        }
    }
    
    protected BaseScreenBinding getBaseBinding() {
        return baseBinding;
    }

    protected abstract int getContentAreaLayoutId();
}
```

you can now use ViewBinding in your child activity, your layout was inflated  by BaseActivity, in child you will bind to it.

```
class ChildActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: StandardContentSettingsBinding

    override fun getContentAreaLayoutId(): Int = R.layout.standard_content_settings

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Layout was inflated in BaseActivity, so now only bind to it.
        binding = StandardContentSettingsBinding.bind(getBaseBinding().pnContent)

        //This should work now
        binding.edURL.setText("test")
    }
}
```

In the child activity, calling `StandardContentSettingsBinding.bind(View)`, is different from `inflate()`, as it doesn't create a new view hierarchy but instead uses the existing one, which is what you want in this case.

some references:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding